# using date format with oracle and mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, database, oracle

Hi All
what is the best way to write SQL statement that is compatible with mysql,oracle,and mssql
database.
for example when i try to execute this:

```
INSERT INTO "table_name ("date") VALUES (to_date('2011-02-11 16:48:08','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

it works in oracle,but this query will give error: to_date is not exist when i  try to execute it in MYSQL database.
 but this follwoing SQL works on mysql and not work in oracle:

```
INSERT INTO t_sys_log (date) VALUES ('2011-11-11');
```

So can you please help me to solve date problem compatibility in mysql and oracle and tell me if there is a way  to make standard SQL statement works in rracle,mssql, and mysql ?
Thank You

Comment: I don't think SQL standards include date functions, so this could be a bit difficult...

Answer (score 4):

Try the ANSI standard DATE literal

> INSERT INTO t_sys_log (date) VALUES (
>   date '2011-12-31');

Comment: Does SQL Server support this syntax? I know Oracle and MySQL do, but I haven't seen it in the MS docs.

Comment: @Vadim: no, SQL Server does not support ANSI date literals (PostgresQL, DB2, H2 and HSQLDB do support this as well)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to_date will not be available to both databases, as it is a SQL extension which was only offered by Oracle.

It gets more challenging the deeper you go.  Date is not quite the same thing as Timestamp, so you'll find yourself stuck where you'll want Timestamps in some databases and Dates in others.  This is because there are databases where Date only contains a calendar date, and not any associated hours, minutes, and seconds.

MSSQL dates are also subject to the platform's timezone rules, while other databases don't hold dates subject to timezone rules in the same manner.

In the end, if you really want it to work correctly, you need to write a software layer which translates dates into the formats required by the underlying database, giving up on the "one SQL statement to do all dates".

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that same problem.  Unfortunately I couldn't find a good way to do it.  Instead I created a plugable "helper" class (this was in Java), that was set along with the database driver.  It had methods to create parts of the SQL statement that were DBMS specific.